# Replace date with x format php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query stored in database i want to make it as generic command 
so, for example

```
select a,b,c 
from table 
where b 
    between 13-08-1998 
    and 14-09-1998
```

which should be converted to

```
select a,b,c 
from table 
where b 
    between xx-xx-xxxx 
    and xx-xx-xxxx.
```

I will store this command and retrieve it to create a query.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what exactly you want to achieve along with some code please?

Comment: Note that 13 - 8 - 1998 = 1993

Comment: @Varin i will be fetching sql statement to my php and the sql statement should displayed as present above x format so that i would write a different command from it

Comment: (I meant -1993, obviously!!)

Comment: @Strawberry sry for giving - it should be /

Comment: 13 divided by 8 divided by 1998 equals 0.0008

Comment: ....why do you store queries in your database?

Comment: it makes no sense, just use prepared statement and bind the values in proper format. That kind of logic should not be stored in db.

Answer (score 4):

We call this a stored procedure

[Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

You can execute SQL code from your procedure with parameters like a function.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN d1 DATE, IN d2 DATE)
  BEGIN
    SELECT a,b,c 
    FROM table 
    WHERE b BETWEEN d1 AND d2;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the query with argument placeholders and replace them with appropriate values before running, e.g.:

```
select a,b,c 
from table 
where b 
    between <start_date> 
    and <end_date>
```

Before executing, you can use `str_replace()` function to substitute the values, e.g.:

```
$query = str_replace('<start_date>', '1998-08-13', $query);
$query = str_replace('<end_date>', '1998-09-14', $query);
```